# Which operator do I need to overwrite to check if a self-defined object exist in the list?

Tags: python, list, overwrite

For example, I have a self defined class, like this:

```
 class Alarm(object):
        def __init__(self, alarmId, msg):
            self.alarmId = alarmId
            self.msg = msg

        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.alarmId == other.alarmId

    aList = list()
    a = Alarm(1, "hello")
    b = Alarm(1, "good")
    aList.append(a)
    aList.append(b)
```

Alarms with same Id are considered same, so "a" and "b" is actually same. I want to check if same Alarm already exist in the list, if it already existed , then no need to add it to the list.

```
if a in aList: # I wish when this "in" called, I could call one member function of a to match the whole list
   pass
```

But which function do I need to overwrite to do this? I tried `__eq__`, but it could not accomplish what I want.

Comment: `I tried __eq__` - Please show that as well.

Comment: __eq__ only return true for the 1st element, when comparing the 2nd element, it fails every time.

Comment: Your class is wrong. missing self in constructor.

Comment: @Marcin, I updated the code, but this is not the reason.

Comment: *Alarms with same Id are considered same, so "a" and "b" is actually same.*  But `a` and `b` have **different** `alarmId`s

Comment: @jedwards, sorry , I made stupid typo error. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think is what you are after (assuming you compering using `self.alarmId`):

```
class Alarm(object):
    def __init__(self, alarmId, msg):
        self.alarmId = alarmId
        self.msg = msg

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, self.__class__)
            and self.alarmId == other.alarmId)


aList = list()
a = Alarm(1, "hello")
b = Alarm(2, "good")
aList.append(a)
aList.append(b)

if a in aList:
    print("a found")

c = Alarm(3, "good")

if c not in aList:
    print("c not found")
```

Result is:

```
a found
c not found
```

Comment: If the `a` in the `if` statement is the same `a` object that was added to the list, you don't need to override anything in the class, since `object.__eq__` tests identity by default. It's only if you're testing with a different object with the same `alarmId` that you'd need an `__eq__` method.

Comment: @Blckknght  I think you right. But still I think its good to show more general way, in case some more complicated equality check is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Deducing from your question, I think you are looking for a conditionall `append()` function for your list. This would then be something like the following:

```
def listadd(list, toadd):
    for alarm in list:
        if alarm == toadd:
            return false

    list.append(toadd)
    return true
```

You could use this function to add alarms to your list and it checks right away if the alarm is in the list. This is obviously not an overloaded function or operator but it should work.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**
You can call the function with the list you want to add to and the item you want to add. It returns a boolean flag if the item was added or not.

Comment: This code is all wrong. You're returning after comparing only the first item, not all items, and you're manually calling the `__eq__` method, when you should be using the `==` operator that calls it (or simply `toadd in list`, which will also use `__eq__` after doing an identity check).